# scrollnav.js subsections not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

So I just stumbled upon [scrollnav.js](http://scrollnav.com/) and it seems really good. On the documentation it says it supports sub sections and can be activated using key:value pairs. I did set the subSections key to true but I don't see it working. What I would like to see is something like on [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) sidebar. Where the sub sections are indented. I would like to have h2 as the main sections and h3 elements as subsections. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To use sub-sections with scrollnav.js set the parameter to a selector for your sub-sections. It's a little bit confusing because the default value for `subSections` is `false`, but to active it you specify a selector instead of `true`.

Example config:

```
$('#container').scrollNav({
    sections: '.section-parent',
    subSections: '.section-item'
});
```

Example HTML:

```
<h2 class="section-parent">Parent 1</h2>
<p>Content...</p>

<h3 class="section-item">Child A</h3>
<p>Content...</p>

<h3 class="section-item">Child B</h3>
<p>Content...</p>

<h2 class="section-parent">Parent 2</h2>
<p>Content...</p>
```

This will result in a nested side navigation which looks kinda like this:

- Parent 1

  - Child A
  - Child B
- Parent 2